# is there some kind of object representation software that you can control remotely through some kind of api?

Tags: c++, object

What it should do is represent objects of various types, but you should be able to control the representation remotely through some network-based api from another application (xml idealy). What I want to do is to have the logic of my application written in C++, where many kinds of "objects" are involved. I'd like to be able to manage these objects visually, but I do not want to write the visual part of the code. So I should have some kind of server written in C++ that will provide the logic for a client that will display the logic. Oh, by the way, this magic visual client should be free software and be able to run in GNU/Linux :D

Comment: Your question is too vague.  You want the GUI to control the representation of the objects - is that like whether they'll appear in circles or squares, whether member functions will be overlaid...?   Then you say you want to "manage" the objects... does that mean trigger member functions, create and destroy instances...?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much work you want to do - you could output your object graph as an SVG file, and display that with a good image viewer.

It's hard to suggest anything more without knowing what kind of objects, how many of them, and what the relationships are though.